# Determine Access rights for a role

Tags: security

I'm having trouble finding a good way to determine the Access Rights for a given role. Is there a easy way to get a list of items, that a given role have been granted access to, without iterating the entire content tree?

Comment: Do you want to do that programmatically? Or see those items in a UI?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko  programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

[Sitecore Powershell Extensions](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx?sc_lang=en) comes with a script which will return you all the items with security information on them. You can filter the data to specific path and select one account you are interested in.

[image]

You will get the information in form of a report.  You can also have a sneak peak into the script which should be in `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/Content Reports/Reports/Content Audit/Items with security for an account`

[More information about the cmdlets](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Get-ItemAcl.html)

---

**UPDATE**

In case you would like to do this programmatically you can execute SQL query on the database:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sitecore_master].[dbo].[SharedFields] where fieldid = '{DEC8D2D5-E3CF-48B6-A653-8E69E2716641}'
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this from code. But I will try to see if the functionality used by the powershell plugin, could point me in the right way.

Comment: @MikkelNielsen you can always see how this is done in the script. I assume it iterates over all items but it's worth checking.

Comment: That would also be my idea. Im not a fan of this, but I guess there is no other way. Thanks.